# Getting table information previously inputted to table in js

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add a new table row and info for every function trigger. The problem is that i need to extract the previous information inputted into the new rows. How would i go about getting this information, to then calculate other stuff with it?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rabattvarsleren</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="input">
<button onclick="leggtil()" id="leggtil">Legg til</button><br><br><br><br>
<br><br>
<table id="yeet">
<tr>
    <th id="total">Total: </th>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function leggtil() {

var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);

var table = document.getElementById("yeet");

var row = table.insertRow(0);

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

cell1.innerHTML = input;

}
```

Comment: You could get the content with a loop to go through all table rows and cells, and store content in an array. You'll want to use `.childNodes()` ([Doc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes))

Comment: How would i go about storing the info in an array?

Comment: It's (**much**) easier with JQuery. I'm not good without it. But basically you get `innerHTML` of each `td` in each `tr`.